# OpenERP / Odoo using domain for many2one in xml view

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I try to set invisible attribute to a field depending on a field in many2one relation:

In fact, I have a model M1 with a field *option* and a field *m2_id* which is a m2o relation to model M2 that contains a field category (a selection field with values val1/val2)

*M1: option (text), m2_id (many2one)*

*M2: category (selection)*

My purpose is to show/hide the field *option* depending on the value of m2.category

Normally this must work:

```
<field name="m2_id" />
<field name="option" attrs="{'invisible': [('m2_id.category','=','val1')]}" />
```

But this generates a runtime error:

```
Error: unknown field m2_id.category in domain [["m2_id.category","=","val1"]]
```

I tried to set the attribute directly like this:

```
<field name="option" invisible="[('m2_id.category','=','val1')]" />
```

but it expects a value not an expression. so, it's considered as *True* all the time.

Please any idea or suggestion ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may make related field for it and than add field on a attrs after than it will work fine.

For example:

```
'category': fields.related('m2_id', 'category', type="char", relation='target_table_name', readonly=True, string="Category"),
```

now use in xml like

```
<field name="m2_id" />
<field name="category" invisible="1"/>
<field name="option" attrs="{'invisible': [('category','=','val1')]}" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. A small problem with this method is that the field is calculated from server side, so it needs a call to m2_id on_change function to update the field category, differently from the behavior of domains that is refreshed automatically (from client side) each time m2_id field has changed..

Comment: yes agree just you need to make a on_change of m2_id and return value with category after your job is done.

Comment: Exactly, that what I did actually. But I found it strange to do not work with domain. Thanks for your help.

--For any useful purpose, the implementation of on_change function (not necessary the best way)

`def onchange_func(self, cr, uid, ids, m2_id, context):
        if m2_id:
            for obj in self.pool.get('model.m2').browse(cr, uid, [m2_id], context):
               return {
                    'value': {
                       'category': obj.category
                   }
               }
       return {
           'value': {
               'category': ''
           }
       }`